# file-saver.js, I get error when saveAs is called?

Tags: javascript, filesaver.js

```
var FileSaver = require("file-saver");

function SaveMod()
{  
    console.group("Save Mod")
    console.log("Saving mod!")
    const output:any = document.getElementById("textoutput");
    console.log("Got document HTML element!")
    const rawManifest = output.value;
    console.log("Got raw manifest!")
    const packedMod = new Blob([rawManifest], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"})
    console.log("Packed manifest into blob!")
    FileSaver.saveAs(packedMod, "manifest.json");
    console.log("Saved manifest as manifest.json!")
}
```

This is a plain old html webpage that I would like to save the contents of `rawManifest` when called, however everything else in the script works, except `FileSaver.saveAs()` which gives me

`Uncaught TypeError: FileSaver is undefined SaveMod http://127.0.0.1:5500/SaveMod.js:11 onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/:1`

The package was installed with npm

Comment: `require` is a node thing, unless you have some build system you can't `require` in the client.

Comment: thank you! so im guessing I would just reference it normally using html?